# Directive to randomly show/hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, angular.js

This directive works fine but I have the feeling that I'm not doing it the "angular way" with `.attr('hide', 'true')`. Is there a better way to show or hide elements from a directive?

```
app.directive('myRandomshow', function() {
  // Show a random element from child elements

  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  return {
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // Ensure everything is initialy hidden
      element.children().attr('hide', 'true');
      scope.$on('event::event', function() {
        // Show result
        element.children().attr('hide', 'true');
        element.children().eq(randomIntFromInterval(2, element.children().length - 1)).removeAttr('hide');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if this is incorrect but it appears that this code utilizes jQuery methods like [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children), [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr), [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq) and [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr). Many would argue that this is far from the "angularJS way" of developing such code.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295249/1575353) explains:

> AngularJS is a framework that handles "data binding" for you, meaning it will (and should) take charge of keeping your model (e.g. `$scope`) and view (the markup) in synch. You should usually not interfere with this behavior, unless there is a very specific reason to do so. A quite lengthy but interesting read on this and related topics can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1575353) (which incidentally was answered to a question about when it is okay to use jQuery yourself).
>
> Long story short: **don't update the DOM inside your controller / scope**.

Instead of updating the DOM using jQuery methods, the [ngHide directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) could be used. In order to do that from the directive one might need to utilize properties stored in the controller that would control the values used for the `ng-hide` attribute on each child element.

A demonstration of this is below. There are three buttons labeled `1`, `2` and `3` and all are hidden by default. Clicking the button above them will randomly select one button to show (and of course hide the others, similar to the original code).

```js
angular.module('sampleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.children = Array(3).fill(0).map((value, id) => ({
      id: id + 1,
      hidden: false
    }));
  }])
  .directive('myRandomshow', function() {
    // Show a random element from child elements
    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }
    return {
      link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.children.forEach(child => child.hidden = true);
        scope.$on('event::event', function() {
          // Show result
          const indexToShow = randomIntFromInterval(1, scope.children.length);
          scope.children.forEach((child, index) => child.hidden = (index + 1) != indexToShow);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <button ng-click="$emit('event::event')">Show a randomly selected child</button>
    <div my-randomshow>
      <button ng-repeat="(key, child) in children track by key" ng-hide="child.hidden">{{ child.id }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```